# How to use end datetime in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, datetime, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In our app it is really important to also save the end datetime of a new data.

For example, if writing a new message, I would like it to be visible for users only ten hours. With rest api & sql database, I can easily create end datetime  with server time(+ten hours) and save the message in database. When loading messages for users, I can select all messages where end datetime is before now.

How can I do this with Firebase Realtime Database? Maybe with Firebase Cloud Functions? I don't want to use client time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would actually be a good usage example for Cloud Functions.

When saving the message to the database, you can use [`ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue.html#TIMESTAMP) to automatically insert the Firebase server's timestamp, so you could do something like:

```java
public void saveMessage(String content) {
    DatabaseReference messagesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages");

    HashMap<String, Object> message = new HashMap<>();
    message.put("content", content);
    message.put("startTime", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

    messagesRef.push().setValue(message);
}
```

Then you could attach a Cloud Function to the `messages` location to listen for new data. This function could perform the logic of adding 10 hours to the `startTime` value and saving it as `endTime` back to the same child, something like:

```javascript
exports.calculateEndTime = functions.database
    .ref('/messages/{messageId}').onCreate(event => {
      const message = event.data.val();

      // Only calculate endTime if it doesn't already exist.
      if (message && !message.endTime) {
        // Add 10 hours (in milliseconds) to the startTime to obtain the endTime.
        const endTime = message.startTime + (10 * 3600000);

        // Update the Firebase Database with the new endTime value.
        return event.data.adminRef.update({
          endTime: endTime
        });
      }
    });
```

Finally, to query the list of messages to only obtain those where the `endTime` has not yet passed, you could do something like:

```
// Obtain the server time using the .info/serverTimeOffset value.
DatabaseReference offsetRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/serverTimeOffset");
offsetRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        // Calculate the estimated server time based on the offset.
        double offset = snapshot.getValue(Double.class);
        double estimatedServerTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + offset;

        // Use this server time to get the messages.
        getMessages(estimatedServerTimeMs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) { }
});

public void getMessages(double endTime) {
    DatabaseReference messagesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages");

    // Create a query to limit results where endTime is greater than the current time.
    Query messagesQuery = messagesRef.orderByChild("endTime").startAt(endTime);

    messagesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot message : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // ...
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
    });
}
```

This example first grabs the [clock skew value (from `.info/serverTimeOffset`)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#clock-skew) to calculate the estimated current server time and then uses this in a `startAt()` query to only return messages with an `endTime` after the current time.

---

There's likely a few other ways to approach this too, like obtaining the server timestamp and performing the logic above while saving the message, or even just querying on the `startTime` (using `startAt` 10 hours ago).

However, using the Cloud Functions route is a good way to ensure that the `endTime` is calculated server-side, saving of a new message is performed quickly and the messages actually contain an `endTime` value in the database.

Comment: How to handle end time when reading messages from the database? If only showing messages that has not ended yet.

Comment: I've added an example for this too.